# XCode Build Results: why is it so amazingly complex even for a hello world console app?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, gcc

I have looked at build result for a simple hello world console app to see command line for compilation. Why is it so complex ? How can I then automate things if it is such complex ?

Answer (score 2):

If you intend to automate builds of Xcode projects, use xcodebuild(1).

Answer (score 2):

Your xcodeproj file contains all of the settings that you would need to specify on the command line if you were to call gcc directly.  If you run xcodebuild all you need to do is specify your xcodeproj file, the target, the configuration, and the SDK to use.  Everything else is done automatically.

Run "man xcodebuild" for more information.

Answer (score 1):

XCode specifies an immense number of command line options for the compiler and linker with fully qualified path names. When working at the command line you'll frequently use defaults instead of specifying all the options the IDE does. Make or some other build tool is your friend for automation.